# React JS Google Map Markers only shows after refresh

Tags: ajax, database, google-maps, reactjs, geocoding

Thank you for looking at this.
I am pulling data from an AJAX call to a geocoder then then to google maps to place markers. The map loads fine and the data passes to the markers but only when I refresh the page. I have been trying to put a setTimeout function in but am having a hard time figuring where to put it and am not sure if that is the best way to fix the problem.

Thanks again for the help.

```
   var Location = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function(){
    return {
     petTrip: []
     }
     },

    getAllpetTripFromServer: function(){
     var self = this;
     $.ajax({
     method: 'GET',
     url: '/travel'
     }).done(function(data){
     console.log(data, "I am the data from line 17");
     self.setState({ petTrip: data })
     })
    },

   componentDidMount: function(){
   this.getAllpetTripFromServer();
  },

  render: function(){
   return (
    <div>
     <AllpetTrip petTrip={this.state.petTrip}/>
    </div>
   )
  }
 });

 var AllpetTrip = React.createClass({
  render: function(){
    var trips = this.props.petTrip.map(function(item){
    return <Geolocator start={item.startPoint}/>
   });
   return (
    <div>
      { trips }
    </div>
   )
  }
});

 var Geolocator = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function(){
  return {
    location: []
   }
 },
  allLocations: [],
  getLocations: function(){
  var self = this;
  var key = { key: 'AIzaSyC9Zst0uBpxGJ2P4LLv3IMATpN9Ppl4ImI'};
  var coder = geocoder(key);
  var arr = [];
  var geo = coder.find(this.props.start, function(err, data){
    self.allLocations.push(data[0]);
  })
  },

 componentDidMount: function(){
   this.getLocations();
 },

  render: function(){
  var startPoints = this.allLocations ?      this.allLocations.map(function(item){
    return <Marker position={
      { lat: item.location.lat, lng: item.location.lng}
    } icon={'img/marker.png'}/>
    }) : null;


  return (
    <div id="google-map">
      <MapLoader>
      <GoogleMap
       defaultZoom={4}
       center={{lat: 40., lng: -99.000}}>
      >

        { startPoints }

    </GoogleMap>
    </MapLoader>
    </div>

    )
   }
 });

 module.exports = Location;
```

Answer (score 1):

Maintain self.allLocations.push(data[0]); in the state

Your allLocations is crucial to the render function and should be in state

```
var Geolocator = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function(){
  return {
    location: [],
    allLocations: []
   }
 },
  allLocations: [],
  getLocations: function(){
  var self = this;
  var key = { key: 'AIzaSyC9Zst0uBpxGJ2P4LLv3IMATpN9Ppl4ImI'};
  var coder = geocoder(key);
  var arr = [];
  var allLocations =[];
  var geo = coder.find(this.props.start, function(err, data){
    allLocations.push(data[0]);
   this.setState({
        allLocations: allLocations
   })

  }.bind(this)
  },

 componentDidMount: function(){
   this.getLocations();
 },

  render: function(){
  var startPoints = this.allLocations ?      this.state.allLocations.map(function(item){
    return <Marker position={
      { lat: item.location.lat, lng: item.location.lng}
    } icon={'img/marker.png'}/>
    }) : null;


  return (
    <div id="google-map">
      <MapLoader>
      <GoogleMap
       defaultZoom={4}
       center={{lat: 40., lng: -99.000}}>
      >

        { startPoints }

    </GoogleMap>
    </MapLoader>
    </div>

    )
   }
 });

 module.exports = Location;
```